# Convert TFS workspace from local to server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm using Eclipse with Team Explorer Everywhere plugin and I cannot find button to edit workspace properties as in Visual Studio. So how can I convert TFS workspace from local to server in Eclipse under Linux OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *create* or ***edit*** a workspace, you can specify whether its location is **Local** or **Server**.  To edit the workspace follow below steps:

1. In **Project Explorer** or **Package Explorer**, right-click an
   Eclipse project that is under version control, point to **Team**,
   and click **Manage Workspaces.**

[image]

2. **The Workspaces dialog** box appears. It shows you the list of your Team Foundation Server workspaces.
3. Then select the one you want to convert, click **Edit**; the **Edit Workspace dialog** box appears just as
       below screenshot:

[image]

***Note: Local workspaces are only supported for Team Foundation Server 2012 and above.***

Comment: Thanks a lot! Life saver!

Comment: i'm using VS2017 however this advise is the first that is shown by Google and it works, thank you